# Fullcalendar day of the week three digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

The below code is working good. Only thing I want to change the day from 2 digit to 3 digit (Mo to Mon) in the column.

I tried changing `columnFormat : 'ddd DD/M',` but its not working.

[image: screen]

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'timelineWeek',
    contentHeight: 610,
    scrollTime: '00:00',
    displayEventTime: false,
    displayEventEnd: false,
    timeFormat: 'h:mma',
    axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
    //slotDuration: '24:00',
    titleFormat: 'ddd DD MMM YYYY',
    columnFormat: 'ddd DD/M',
    resourceAreaWidth: 200,
    defaultView: 'timelineWeek',
    duration: {
      days: 15
    },
    slotDuration: {
      "hours": 12
    },
    slotLabelInterval: {
      "hours": 24
    },
    minTime: "00:00:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",
    height: 610,
    contentHeight: "40",
    header: {
      left: 'prev, today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'oneweek,twoweek,onemonth,oneyear,next'
    },
    views: {
      oneyear: {
        buttonText: 'One Year',
        type: 'timelineYear'
      },
      onemonth: {
        buttonText: 'One Month',
        type: 'timelineMonth'
      },
    },
    //hiddenDays: [ 10 ],
    businessHours: {
      start: '09:00',
      end: '20:00'
    },
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources'
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@1.10.0/dist/scheduler.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@1.10.0/dist/scheduler.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: This thread could be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945482/fullcalendar-columnformat-html   https://jsfiddle.net/puhkv5qd/

Comment: @MuraliNepalli This is the exact snippet of code that I incorporated into my solution. Except I took it a step further and implemented a jQuery plugin and added options for single/multi-line display.

Comment: Because you're in the timeline view, those are actually the slot labels, not the column headers. (In the "agenda" view they're down the left hand side, but timeline essentially flips that view by 90 degrees and adds resources)

Comment: @ADyson its there any to set full width for `fc-scroller-canvas`

Comment: If you have a new problem please ask a separate question about it

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the [slotLabelFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat) parameters to define your new format. Please take note that this option is only available for the scheduler view.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'timelineWeek',
    contentHeight: 610,
    scrollTime: '00:00',
    displayEventTime: false,
    displayEventEnd: false,
    timeFormat: 'h:mma',
    axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
    //slotDuration: '24:00',
    titleFormat: 'ddd DD MMM YYYY',
    columnFormat: 'ddd DD/M',
    slotLabelFormat: 'ddd DD', // <--- I've added this.
    resourceAreaWidth: 200,
    defaultView: 'timelineWeek',
    duration: {
      days: 15
    },
    slotDuration: {
      "hours": 12
    },
    slotLabelInterval: {
      "hours": 24
    },
    minTime: "00:00:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",
    height: 610,
    contentHeight: "40",
    header: {
      left: 'prev, today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'oneweek,twoweek,onemonth,oneyear,next'
    },
    views: {
      oneyear: {
        buttonText: 'One Year',
        type: 'timelineYear'
      },
      onemonth: {
        buttonText: 'One Month',
        type: 'timelineMonth'
      },
    },
    //hiddenDays: [ 10 ],
    businessHours: {
      start: '09:00',
      end: '20:00'
    },
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources'
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@1.10.0/dist/scheduler.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@1.10.0/dist/scheduler.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Nice, it [looks like](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat#timeline-view) you can specify multiple (timeline view only) lines in the title too. My workaround allows multiple lines too. So I essentially engineered a more customizable clone.

Comment: I mean `timelineYear` month not showing after I add `slotLabelFormat`

Comment: @Saravana The documentation explains how you can change the format to add the extra bar back in with the month. Did you try? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/slotLabelFormat

Comment: @ADyson Ok. I will check

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a custom renderer.

```js
viewRender: function(view, element) {
  // Manipulate the DOM here
  return element.find('th.fc-widget-header').renderCalendarHeaders({
    multiLine : false,
    patterns : [ 'ddd', 'DD' ]
  });
}
```

I implemented a `renderCalendarHeaders` jQuery plugin below that is based on a vanilla JS method at the very bottom (unused) of the demo. You should not have to modify this plugin code. Just modify the options you pass in; as seen in the call above.

```js
/* jQuery plugin */
(function($) {
  // Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38962654/1762224
  $.fn.renderCalendarHeaders = function(opts) {
    opts = $.extend({
      multiLine : false,
      patterns : []
    }, opts || {});
    this.each((i, th) => $(th).html(buildDateColumnHeader(moment($(th).data('date')))));
    function buildDateColumnHeader(colDate) {
      var $container = $('<div>').addClass('fc-cell-text-wrapper');
      var textArr = opts.patterns.map(pattern => colDate.format(pattern));
      if (opts.multiLine === true) {
        $container.append(textArr.map(text => $('<span>').addClass('fc-cell-text').text(text)));
      } else {
        $container.append($('<span>').addClass('fc-cell-text').text(textArr.join(' ')));
      }
      return $container;
    }
    return this; // Self-returning
  }
})(jQuery);
```

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'timelineWeek',
    viewRender: renderViewColumns, // OVERRIDE TEXT
    contentHeight: 610,
    scrollTime: '00:00',
    displayEventTime: false,
    displayEventEnd: false,
    timeFormat: 'h:mma',
    axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
    //slotDuration: '24:00',
    titleFormat: 'ddd DD MMM YYYY',
    columnFormat: 'ddd DD/M', // WILL BE OVERIDDEN
    resourceAreaWidth: 200,
    duration: {
      days: 15
    },
    slotDuration: {
      "hours": 12
    },
    slotLabelInterval: {
      "hours": 24
    },
    minTime: "00:00:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",
    height: 610,
    contentHeight: "40",
    header: {
      left: 'prev, today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'oneweek,twoweek,onemonth,oneyear,next'
    },
    views: {
      oneyear: {
        buttonText: 'One Year',
        type: 'timelineYear'
      },
      onemonth: {
        buttonText: 'One Month',
        type: 'timelineMonth'
      },
    },
    //hiddenDays: [ 10 ],
    businessHours: {
      start: '09:00',
      end: '20:00'
    },
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources'
  });
});

/* Call the jQuery plugin on each header. */
function renderViewColumns(view, element) {
  return element.find('th.fc-widget-header').renderCalendarHeaders({
    multiLine : false,
    patterns : [ 'ddd', 'DD' ]
  });
}

/* jQuery plugin */
(function($) {
  // Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38962654/1762224
  $.fn.renderCalendarHeaders = function(opts) {
    opts = $.extend({
      multiLine : false,
      patterns : []
    }, opts || {});
    this.each((i, th) => $(th).html(buildDateColumnHeader(moment($(th).data('date')))));
    function buildDateColumnHeader(colDate) {
      var $container = $('<div>').addClass('fc-cell-text-wrapper');
      var textArr = opts.patterns.map(pattern => colDate.format(pattern));
      if (opts.multiLine === true) {
        $container.append(textArr.map(text => $('<span>').addClass('fc-cell-text').text(text)));
      } else {
        $container.append($('<span>').addClass('fc-cell-text').text(textArr.join(' ')));
      }
      return $container;
    }
    return this; // Self-returning
  }
})(jQuery);

// ==============================================================================
// Original method below...
// ==============================================================================
var MULTI_LINE = false; // Could not pass as an option before.
function __renderViewColumns(view, element) {
  element.find('th.fc-widget-header').each(function() {
    var theDate = moment($(this).data('date')); /* th.data-date="YYYY-MM-DD" */
    $(this).html(buildDateColumnHeader(theDate));
  });

  function buildDateColumnHeader(theDate) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.classList.add('fc-cell-text-wrapper');
    var textArr = [
      theDate.format('ddd'),   // Day of Week
      theDate.format('DD') // Date and Month
    ];
    if (MULTI_LINE === true) {
      textArr.forEach(text => {
        var singleText = document.createElement('span');
        singleText.classList.add('fc-cell-text');
        singleText.textContent = text;
        container.appendChild(singleText);
      });
    } else {
      var allText = document.createElement('span');
      allText.classList.add('fc-cell-text');
      allText.textContent = textArr.join(' ');
      container.appendChild(allText);
    }
    return container;
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.fc-widget-header .fc-cell-text-wrapper .fc-cell-text {
  display: block; /* For separate lines */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@1.10.0/dist/scheduler.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@1.10.0/dist/scheduler.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like [columnFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/columnFormat) was deprecated in favor of [columnHeaderFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/columnHeaderFormat). Have you tried using that property instead of columnFormat?

Comment: That option did not seem to work for me, so I created a workaround. Looks like Nicolas figured out the option though...

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad the slotLabelFormat worked for you.

Comment: I am not OP, lol... Just letting you know the strategy you suggested did not work.

Comment: Oh. haha I guess I should have checked on that.